# How to bind a property of ViewModel to an element in HierarchicalDataTemplate of a Treeview?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls, hierarchicaldatatemplate

How to bind a property of ViewModel to an element in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of a `Treeview` (the property is is out of `HierarchicalDataTemplate.Itemsource`)

this is the example and the probelm is in this line: `Visibility="{Binding IsCheckBoxVisible , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource debuger}}"/>`

```
<UserControl ....>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Roots}" Grid.Row="0">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate >
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigedChildren}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Visibility="{Binding IsCheckBoxVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource debuger}}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Title}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: refer the below http://wpftution.blogspot.in/2012/06/hierarchical-databinding-in-treeview.html

Comment: @ David Bekham : i know how to bind a Hierarchical in Treeview!it wasn't my question!

Comment: @raha Are you facing some problem with `RelativeSource` binding? `RelativeSourceBinding` looks the way to go.

Comment: @akjoshi : yes.when i do something like this: put a checkbox out of Hierarchical   `<CheckBox x:Name="mycheckbox" Visibility="{Binding IsCheckBoxVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`  and bind the main CheckBox  to that,it work's fine:  `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding mycheckbox}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Ischeck}"`

Comment: @akjoshi :but i don't understand why the code's above don't work?

Comment: set DataContext.IsCheckBoxVisible and use the above relativeSource syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsCheckBoxVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource debuger}}"/>
```

Use `DataContext.IsCheckBoxVisible`. Hope this will work

Comment: above you are Binding to UserControl not to the ViewModel of UserControl hence its not working . DataContext is bind to ViewModel and hence it will get this property 'CompletePath' in it

Comment: @ ethicallogics :yes.you right,it was a funny mistake,i made it before!!and repeat it again and waste time!! thank you.